# Сократить слова в хлебных крошках в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Имеется функция вывода хлебных крошек:

```
  function constantine_breadcrumbs() {

  /* === ОПЦИИ === */
  $text['home'] = 'Главная'; // текст ссылки "Главная"
  $text['category'] = '%s'; // текст для страницы рубрики
  $text['search'] = 'Результаты поиска по запросу "%s"'; // текст для страницы с результатами поиска
  $text['tag'] = 'Записи с тегом "%s"'; // текст для страницы тега
  $text['author'] = 'Статьи автора %s'; // текст для страницы автора
  $text['404'] = 'Ошибка 404'; // текст для страницы 404
  $text['page'] = 'Страница %s'; // текст 'Страница N'
  $text['cpage'] = 'Страница комментариев %s'; // текст 'Страница комментариев N'

  $wrap_before = '<ol class="breadcrumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">'; // открывающий тег обертки
  $wrap_after = '</ol><!-- .breadcrumbs -->'; // закрывающий тег обертки
  $before = '<li class="breadcrumbs__current">'; // тег перед текущей "крошкой"
  $after = '</li>'; // тег после текущей "крошки"

  $show_on_home = 0; // 1 - показывать "хлебные крошки" на главной странице, 0 - не показывать
  $show_home_link = 1; // 1 - показывать ссылку "Главная", 0 - не показывать
  $show_current = 1; // 1 - показывать название текущей страницы, 0 - не показывать
  $show_last_sep = 1; // 1 - показывать последний разделитель, когда название текущей страницы не отображается, 0 - не показывать
  /* === КОНЕЦ ОПЦИЙ === */

  global $post;
  $home_url = home_url('/');
  $link = '<li class="home breadcrumb-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">';
  $link .= '<a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="%1$s" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">%2$s</span></a>';
  $link .= '<meta itemprop="position" content="%3$s" />';
  $link .= '</li>';
  $parent_id = ( $post ) ? $post->post_parent : '';
  $home_link = sprintf( $link, $home_url, $text['home'], 1 );

  if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {

    if ( $show_on_home ) echo $wrap_before . $home_link . $wrap_after;

  } else {

    $position = 0;

    echo $wrap_before;

    if ( $show_home_link ) {
      $position += 1;
      echo $home_link;
    }

    if ( is_category() ) {
      $parents = get_ancestors( get_query_var('cat'), 'category' );
      foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $cat ) {
        $position += 1;
        if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
      }
      if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $position += 1;
        $cat = get_query_var('cat');
        echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
        echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
      } else {
        if ( $show_current ) {
          if ( $position >= 1 ) echo $sep;
          echo $before . sprintf( $text['category'], single_cat_title( '', false ) ) . $after;
        } elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
      }

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
      if ( $show_home_link && $show_current || ! $show_current && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
      if ( $show_current ) echo $before . sprintf( $text['search'], get_search_query() ) . $after;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
      if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
      if ( $show_current ) echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;
      elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
      if ( $show_home_link ) echo $sep;
      $position += 1;
      echo sprintf( $link, get_year_link( get_the_time('Y') ), get_the_time('Y'), $position );
      if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;
      elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
      if ( $show_home_link ) echo $sep;
      $position += 1;
      echo sprintf( $link, get_year_link( get_the_time('Y') ), get_the_time('Y'), $position ) . $sep;
      $position += 1;
      echo sprintf( $link, get_month_link( get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m') ), get_the_time('F'), $position );
      if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;
      elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

    } elseif ( is_single() && ! is_attachment() ) {
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $position += 1;
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
        if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf( $link, get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type->name ), $post_type->labels->name, $position );
        if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $catID = $cat[0]->cat_ID;
        $parents = get_ancestors( $catID, 'category' );
        $parents = array_reverse( $parents );
        $parents[] = $catID;
        foreach ( $parents as $cat ) {
          $position += 1;
          if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
          echo sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
        }
        
                 if ( get_query_var( 'cpage' ) ) {
          $position += 1;
          echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_permalink(), get_the_title(), $position );
          echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['cpage'], get_query_var( 'cpage' ) ) . $after;
        } else {
          if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
          elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
        }
      }
      

    } elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
      $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
      if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $position += 1;
        if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf( $link, get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type->name ), $post_type->label, $position );
        echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
      } else {
        if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
        if ( $show_current ) echo $before . $post_type->label . $after;
        elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
      }

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
      $parent = get_post( $parent_id );
      $cat = get_the_category( $parent->ID ); $catID = $cat[0]->cat_ID;
      $parents = get_ancestors( $catID, 'category' );
      $parents = array_reverse( $parents );
      $parents[] = $catID;
      foreach ( $parents as $cat ) {
        $position += 1;
        if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
      }
      $position += 1;
      echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_permalink( $parent ), $parent->post_title, $position );
      if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
      $parents = get_post_ancestors( get_the_ID() );
      foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $pageID ) {
        $position += 1;
        if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf( $link, get_page_link( $pageID ), get_the_title( $pageID ), $position );
      }
      if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
      if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $position += 1;
        $tagID = get_query_var( 'tag_id' );
        echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_tag_link( $tagID ), single_tag_title( '', false ), $position );
        echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
      } else {
        if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
        if ( $show_current ) echo $before . sprintf( $text['tag'], single_tag_title( '', false ) ) . $after;
        elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
      }

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
      $author = get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
      if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $position += 1;
        echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ), sprintf( $text['author'], $author->display_name ), $position );
        echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
      } else {
        if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
        if ( $show_current ) echo $before . sprintf( $text['author'], $author->display_name ) . $after;
        elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
      }

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
      if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
      if ( $show_current ) echo $before . $text['404'] . $after;
      elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

    } elseif ( has_post_format() && ! is_singular() ) {
      if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
      echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

  }
}
```

Но есть проблема - название каждой хлебной крошки хватает весь тайтл, который бывает довольно длинным. Как можно автоматически ограничить вывод названия хлебной крошки например до 5 первых слов?

Есть примеры такой функции, но я не знаю как эту функцию адаптировать к своей:

```
function trim_title_words($count, $after) {
 $title = get_the_title();
 $words = split(' ', $title);
 if (count($words) > $count) {
 array_splice($words, $count);
 $title = implode(' ', $words);
 }
 else $after = '';
 echo $title . $after;
}
```

И

```
trim_title_words(5, '...')
```

Comment: В данном случае я бы рекомендовал не обрезать. а "лишнее" скрывать с пом css. И использовать title в элементах списка/ссылках.